# Connecting to MySQL Database from React?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, express

I've been having problems with connecting to a database. It is a remote database and no matter what I do, it just doesn't work! I've searched all around to no avail. I'm using React for doing so. I just want to make a simple connection and be able to run some queries. Here's the code:

db.js component:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    /*THE VALUES BELOW ARE NOT THE ONES I HAVE TO USE*/
    host: '11.111.11.11', 
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    port: 'port',
    database: 'database'
});

module.exports = db;
```

server.js in my backend folder:

```
const express = require('express');
const db = require('./config/db');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3002;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//ROUTE
app.get("/db", (req, res) => {
    db.query("SELECT * FROM users", (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.send(result);
            console.log(result);
            console.log('Connected!');
        }
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost/${PORT}/`);
});
```

I'm not getting anything from it, not even the logged info I asked for in the console.log()

Thanks for the help, in advance.

Comment: I think this has nothin to do with reactjs itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have just created the connection, however you need also use the connect function to connect to your database. So you need to add a line in your server.js, (I have put a comment near the line that you missed to write.

```
const db = require('./config/db');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3002;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

db.connect(); // you missed this line

//ROUTE
app.get("/db", (req, res) => {
    db.query("SELECT * FROM users", (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.send(result);
            console.log(result);
            console.log('Connected!');
        }
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost/${PORT}/`);
});
```

I think you can also do this in db.js before exporting db.